# Hello world command line LLDB iOS unable to resolve breakpoint in 'main'

Tags: ios, jailbreak, lldb, arm64

I have extracted the `debugserver` and copied it to my jailbroken iPhone 5S. Then I run LLDB on my mac and connect it using the instructions [here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Debugserver).

I copied a simple hello world program written in C and compiled for ARM64 over to my iPhone 5S using SSH/SFTP and chmod it.

I used the command: `./debugserver *:1234 helloworld64_full` where the helloworld64_full is the executable file on the device.

Then I started to connect to the iPhone: `platform select remote-ios` and `process connect connect://localhost:1234` which stops at:

```
Process 442 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x90ed, 0x0000000120085010 dyld`_dyld_start, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
        frame #0: 0x0000000120085010 dyld`_dyld_start
    dyld`_dyld_start:
    -> 0x120085010:  add    x28, sp, 0
   0x120085014:  and    sp, x28, #0xfffffffffffffff0
   0x120085018:  movz   x0, #0
   0x12008501c:  movz   x1, #0
   (lldb) b main
```

However when i start to set breakpoint `b main`. It says:

```
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
WARNING:  Unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations.
```

But when i re-compile the same source program for x86-64 and debug on my mac, i can set the breakpoint. Why is this so? Please advise thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I got it by actually including the file on the lldb client like so:

```
target create --arch arm64 helloworld_full
```

Basically I forgot that the same copy of the executable to be debugged has to be loaded on the client (a.k.a the mac machine)

Comment: When do you call target create ? Because when i am doing it i am getting: (lldb) process continue 
error: invalid process

Comment: @mientus yeah, I have the exact same issue. I've been stuck on it all day. Did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: @mientus, call it from lldb, and when you get process continue error, you have to re-attach.